# How to get last modified column for all tables in a Sybase database

Tags: sybase

I am trying to write a sybase query for how to get a last modified column and timestamp for all the tables in SYBASE database. Please find the sql below. but this is not accuarte one.. it is working in one syabase DB object and not in another environment. Please help me with proper sql.

```
select TableName=object_name(ss.id), RowCnt=st.rowcnt,
ColName=col_name(ss.id,convert(int,substring(ss.colidarray,1,2))),
UpdStatsDate=convert(varchar(20),moddate,100),
DaysAgo=datediff(dd,moddate,getdate())
from sysstatistics ss, systabstats st
where ss.id > 100 and st.id > 100
and ss.id=st.id
and ss.formatid=100
and st.indid in (0,1)
and ss.c4 is not null
order by TableName, ColName
```

Answer (score 4):

Sybase ASE does not keep track when a column was modified last. You can include a column of datatype 'timestamp' in a table, but this value is updated when *any* column in the row is updated. Moreover, such 'timestamp' column so not reflect a real-world clock time, but are an artificial internal counter based on the internal 'database timestamp' (which, again, is not related to what we call 'time' in the real world). For more info on what that timestamp means, see chapter 13 of my book 'Tips, Tricks & recipes for Sybase ASE' (sypron.nl/ttr).

But more importantly, the sysstatistics.moddate column does NOT reflect when a column was updated. Instead, it is the time when the *statistics* for a column were last updated (as a result of running UPDATE STATISTICS).

If you want to keep track of the last update time for a column, you could do this with an UPDATE trigger which detects which columns are updated as well as the time, and records this in a separate table. Note that such a trigger could quickly become a bottleneck in busy systems.